# PHP: How to equal variables with multidimensional arrays in dynamic layout?

Tags: php, arrays

I don't know how exactly to simplify my question, I tried to explain my problem with some detail though. How can I change my one array into a two or multidimensional array (example at the bottom), check the array for one variable (equals current category) and another variable (equals current page), and check to see if page is part of category?

---

**Working code:**

I have the below working code, which allows me to GET the page I'm about to be on and display the proper content (via includes, which aren't shown here).

```
$path = '';
$category = $_GET['category'];
$page = $_GET['page'];
$content = array('home','about','work','contact','404','team','services');

if (!empty($page)) {
    if(in_array($page,$content)) {
        if (!empty($category)) {
            $path = $category . '/' . $category . '_' . $page;
        } else {
            $path = 'content_' . $page;
        }
    }else {
        $page = '404';
        $url = '/' . $page;
        header('Location: ' . $url, true, 404); exit();
    }
}
else {
    $page = 'home';
    $path = 'content_' . $page;
}
```

---

**My problem:**

My problem is where it checks to see if `$page` is found in array `$content`.

I need to do something like this:

```
$main = array('home','about','work','contact','404');
$secondary = array('team','services');
```

...and then in this:

```
        if (in_array($category,$main) && in_array($page,$secondary)) {
            $path = $category . '/' . $category . '_' . $page;
        }
```

Even if that worked there would still be a flaw. If `$category == $main` and `$page == $secondary` but `$secondary` doesn't equal a page that's under the current category, the page will still open up but there won't be any content because it doesn't actually exist.

- Let's say the about category has two pages, team and services, and the contact category also had two pages, quote and support.
- If `$category == $main` and `$page == $secondary`, with `$category` being `/about` and `$page` being `/team` the result would be the url `/about/team` which would be correct.
- But if `$category` was `/about` and `$page` was `/contact` the result would technically also be correct according to the code but the url would be `/about/contact` which would show a blank page.

---

**My ideas:**

I'm thinking that two dimensional arrays would be better? This is where I'm stuck!

Something like this:

```
$content = array(
    array('Home'),
    array('About','Team','Services'),
    array('Work'),
    array('Contact','Quote','Support'),
    array('404')
);
```

Or this:

```
$main = array('home','about','work','contact','404');
$secondary = array(
    array('About','Team','Services'),
    array('Contact','Quote','Support')
);
```

If you need anymore information from me, just ask. All help is appreciated, what is the best way to do this and if you could get me started on the right path at the least I would be grateful!

---

EDIT: Here's what we have so far.

```
<?php 

    $path = '';
    $category = $_GET['category'];
    $page = $_GET['page'];

    function getUrl($category, $page) {
        $pages = array(
            'home',
            'about' => array('team', 'services'),
            'work',
            'contact' => array('quote', 'support'),
            '404'
        );

        if (!is_null($category)) {
            if(array_key_exists($category, $pages) && in_array($page, $pages[$category])) {
                return $category . '/' . $category . '_' . $page;
            }

            return '404';
        } else if (in_array($page, $pages)) {
            return 'content_' . $page;
        }

        return '404';
    }

          if($page == 'home'){
                // stuff for home here
    }else if($page == 'about'){ 
                $page_title = 'About'; 
    }else if($page == 'work'){ 
                $page_title = 'Work'; 
    }else if($page == 'contact'){ 
                $page_title = 'Contact'; 
    }else if($page == '404'){ 
                $page_title = 'Oops! (404)'; 
                $path = 'content_404';
    }
    $page_class = 'page-' . $page;
    $web_url = "http://mrobertsdesign.ca";

    // Page Start

    include('includes/header.php');
    include('content/' . $path . '.php');
    include('includes/footer.php');
?>
```

Comment: *Way* too much information, and too long of a post.  Please pare it down and ask clear, concise question.

Comment: @Madbreaks will do that right now, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah you can use a two-dimensional array. The key to resolving your issue is to recognize that PHP supports associative arrays - similar to `Dictionary` from Python or `Map` from Java (except unlike `Map`, PHP's arrays are not type-restricted).

In essence, you can assign a `$key => $value` pairing for each array entry if you so wish. Now stop reading for a moment and think about how you can solve your problem with this knowledge. If you can get it, awesome; if not, keep going!

So we want to set up an array where the `$key`s are the allowed category names, and the `$value`s are the set of pages allowed for that category (a sub-array). Here's how that would look (try running this code on [WriteCodeOnline](http://writecodeonline.com/php/)):

```php
function getUrl($category, $page) {
    $pages = array(
        'home',
        'about' => array('team', 'services'),
        'work',
        'contact' => array('quote', 'support'),
        '404'
    );

    if (!is_null($category)) {
        if(array_key_exists($category, $pages) && in_array($page, $pages[$category])) {
            return $category . '/' . $category . '_' . $page;
        }

        // Category doesn't exist or page for category not found
        return '404';
    } else if (in_array($page, $pages)) {
        return 'content_' . $page;
    }

    return '404';
}


// Expected url: 'about/about_team'
var_dump(getUrl('about', 'team'));

// Expected url: 'contact/contact_quote'
var_dump(getUrl('contact', 'quote'));

// Expected url: 'content_home' - Page 'home' exists without category as a page
var_dump(getUrl(null, 'home'));

// Expected url: '404' - Page 'home' of category 'contact' does not exist.
var_dump(getUrl('contact', 'home'));

// Expected url: '404' - Page 'notexist' of category 'contact' does not exist.
var_dump(getUrl('contact', 'notexist'));
```

So you can see that `$category = 'about'` and `$page = 'team'` leads to an existing page...

Whereas `$category = 'about'` and `$page = 'contact'` would not.

See: http://php.net/array_key_exists

See: http://php.net/in_array

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to incorporate this and test it in about 3 hours when I'm back in front of my comp!

Comment: I literally just walked in the door, going to try it right now!

Comment: I've added the new code to the bottom of my question, it doesn't seem to be working for About or Contact, they're the only ones with arrays.

Comment: Hey, sorry I fell asleep. I got the code a bit wrong; we need to use two functions: `array_key_exists` and `in_array`. I've edited my answer and provided some example code.

Comment: It's okay my friend, you gotta get your sleep!

Comment: I appreciate your effort, although I'm not sure how to incorporate this, I've included the whole page (really not that big) at the bottom of my question with your code

Comment: Just utilize the function, passing in `$category` and `$page` to get `$path`. So after the function declaration: `$path = getUrl($category, $page);`. Here's how I'd do it, on pastebin: http://pastebin.com/F2H6biHP

Comment: You've done more than enough, thanks for showing me how you'd incorporate that. We were moving outside of my comfort zone with PHP, I wrote the original code but I'm always learning! I haven't tested that but it should work so I'll get back to you tonight when I get home if anything!

Comment: Sure! Don't be afraid to ask me about anything I've written if you need some clarification. Gotta start somewhere. :)

Comment: Okay, I just got home and I'm testing it, it works great, just one more problem, the pages with arrays still don't show - the subpages like "/about/team" will show fine, but pages that have subpages like "/about" will come back as a 404 error. "/home" and "/contact" show fine so it's just the pages with arrays!

Comment: You can see it in your example actually with `var_dump(getUrl(null, 'about'));`

Comment: Remove the `return '404'` (line 20 from my pastebin) in the `if(!is_null($category))` block, and make the else-if statement (line 21 from the same pastebin) `else if(in_array($page, $pages) || array_key_exists($page, $pages))`.

Comment: I don't suppose you'd be up for a challenge, I'm trying to make this work with three dimensional arrays, so I want to actually insert another array into the second group of arrays to create another layer - I did post the question here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29597169/how-to-make-code-work-with-multidimensional-arrays) but since you helped me write this in the first place I thought I would just shoot you a message and see if you're interested! Thanks