# How to make code work with multidimensional arrays?

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following code, it works with my htaccess file to dynamically display content via PHP includes into the same welcome.php page. This is just a part of the whole page. The first block of code is the working code with two dimensional arrays. This code finds the path of the included files and creates the general structure of the website.

```
$category   = $_GET['category'];
$page       = $_GET['page'];

function getUrl($category, $page) {
    $pages = array(
        'home',
        'design' => array('about', 'events', 'contact'),
        'community' => array('about', 'events', 'contact'),
        'philanthropy' => array('about', 'events', 'contact'),
        '404'
    );
    if (!is_null($category)) {
        if(array_key_exists($category, $pages) && in_array($page, $pages[$category])) {
            return $category . '/' . $category . '_' . $page;
        }
    } elseif (in_array($page, $pages) || array_key_exists($page, $pages)) {
        return 'content_' . $page;
    }
    return 'content_404';
}
$path = getUrl($category, $page);
```

I'm currently using two dimensional arrays, I want to be able to use three dimensional arrays though to create another layer of pages, and I'm having trouble getting this to work though... here's what I've tried so far:

```
$category   = $_GET['category'];
$subcat     = $_GET['subcat'];
$page       = $_GET['page'];

function getUrl($category, $subcat, $page){
    $pages = array(
        'home',
        'design' => array(
            'about' => array('services', 'partners'), 
            'events', 
            'contact'
        ),
        'community' => array(
            'about' => array('services', 'partners'), 
            'events', 
            'contact'
        ),
        'philanthropy' => array(
            'about' => array('services', 'partners'), 
            'events', 
            'contact'
        ),
        '404'
    );

    if (!is_null($category)) {
        if(array_key_exists($category, $pages) && in_array($page, $pages[$category])) {
            return $category . '/' . $category . '_' . $page;
        }
    } elseif (in_array($page, $pages) || array_key_exists($page, $pages)) {
        return 'content_' . $page;
    }
    return 'content_404';
}
$path = getUrl($category, $subcat, $page);
```

This will be the .htaccess file:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/?$ welcome.php?page=$1 [NC]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/?$ welcome.php?category=$1&page=$2 [NC]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/?$ welcome.php?category=$1&subcat=$2&page=$3 [L,NC]
```

The site structure I'm going for is something like this:

```
Home

Design
-- About
---- Services
---- Partners
-- Events
-- Contact

Community
-- About
---- Services
---- Partners
-- Events
-- Contact

Philanthropy
-- About
---- Services
---- Partners
-- Events
-- Contact

--------------------------

Example:
/design                = $page
/design/about          = $category/$page
/design/about/services = $category/$subcat/$page
```

Multidimensional arrays are something I'm still getting used to, not sure exactly how to get this to work with three dimensional arrays... Basically what I'm trying to do is to get the code to work with the array.

Comment: What are you trying to do with it? You need to outline that in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a version of your function that supports three dimensions:

```
function getUrl($category, $page, $subpage){
    $pages = array(
        'home',
        'design' => array(
            'about' => array('services', 'partners'), 
            'events', 
            'contact'
        ),
        'community' => array(
            'about' => array('services', 'partners'), 
            'events', 
            'contact'
        ),
        'philanthropy' => array(
            'about' => array('services', 'partners'), 
            'events', 
            'contact'
        ),
        '404'
    );

    if (!is_null($category) && !is_null($subpage)) {
        // Handle subpage.
        if (array_key_exists($category, $pages) && array_key_exists($subpage, $pages[$category]) && in_array($page, $pages[$category][$subpage])) {
            return $category . '/' . $subpage . '/' . $category . '_' . $subpage . '_' . $page;
        }
    } elseif (!is_null($category)) {
        // Handle page.
        if (array_key_exists($category, $pages) && (in_array($page, $pages[$category]) || array_key_exists($page, $pages[$category]))) {
            return $category . '/' . $category . '_' . $page;
        }
    } elseif (in_array($page, $pages) || array_key_exists($page, $pages)) {
        return 'content_' . $page;
    }

    return 'content_404';
}
```

The hardest part is just making sure that every key exists and that $subpage and $category is set. Note that I'm not sure what sorts of arguments your function expects but I added the null check for $subpage just in case.

Comment: What this is creating is what is going to be in this: `include('content/' . $path . '.php');` I did make an edit to the code above actually, to clarify it a little, so it wil result with: category/subcat/page -- where 'page' will always be the content that is currently showing

Comment: @Matthew so if we had: `/design/about/services = $category/$subpage/$page` then $subpage would be set to "about"?

Comment: Sorry for the wait my friend, all seems to be going good so far, just doing a check =)

Comment: I did edit the code a little, when $category wasn't set but $subpage was set it would go to $page regardless, so here is what I did: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/31d031144139ddda572e9e9419f602f830fb03c7 -- if you think that can be better then go for it =)

Answer (score 0):

I hope this help,,

```
function getUrl($category = FALSE, $page = FALSE, $subpage = FALSE){

    $pages = array(
        'home',
        'design' => array(
            'about' => array('services', 'partners'), 
            'events', 
            'contact'
        ),
        'community' => array(
            'about' => array('services', 'partners'), 
            'events', 
            'contact'
        ),
        'philanthropy' => array(
            'about' => array('services', 'partners'), 
            'events', 
            'contact'
        ),
        '404'
    );

    if(!is_null($category) && !is_null($page) && !is_null($subpage)){ // validate category, page and subpage

        foreach($pages as $keys=>$val){

            if(is_array($pages[$keys])){

                if($category == $keys && in_array($page, $pages[$keys])){

                    return $category . '/' . $category . '_' . $page;

                }

            }else {


            }

            if($keys == "design" && $category == "design"){


                    foreach($pages['design'] as $key=>$vall){

                        if($page == $key){

                            if(is_array($vall)){

                                if(in_array($subpage, $vall)){

                                    return $category . '/' . $category . '_' . $page . '/' . $subpage;

                                }

                            }else {

                                return $category . '/'. $page;

                            }
                        }

                    }

            }

        }

    }
    else if(!is_null($category) && !is_null($page)) { // validate category and page only

        if(array_key_exists($category, $pages) && in_array($page, $pages[$category])) {

            return $category . '/' . $category . '_' . $page;

        }

    }
    else if(!is_null($page)){ // validate page only

        if (in_array($page, $pages) || array_key_exists($page, $pages)) {

            return 'content_' . $page;

        }

    }else {

        // no parameter set

    }

}
```

recommending you to use !empty instead of !is_null because it will return true if you set '' on parameter

Answer (score 0):

First you have to check for the page existence.

Suppose this is you array

```
$pages = array(
    'home',
    'design' => array(
        'about' => array('services', 'partners'), 
        'events', 
        'contact'
    ),
    'community' => array(
        'about' => array('services', 'partners'), 
        'events', 
        'contact'
    ),
    'philanthropy' => array(
        'about' => array('services', 'partners'), 
        'events', 
        'contact'
    ),
    '404'
);
```

Then checking for page existence

```
if(in_array($page, $pages)){
    /* Page found here we have to check the structure of this page. */
    if(is_array($pages[$page])){
        if(in_array($category, $pages[$page])){
            /* Category found here we have to check the structure of this category. */
            if(is_array($pages[$page][$category])){
                if(in_array($subpage, $pages[$page][$category])){
                    /* Sub Page found return it. */
                    return $category . '/' . $subpage . '/' . $category . '_' . $subpage . '_' . $page;
                }
            }

            /* All done we don't have more items in the list. */
            return $category . '/' . $category . '_' . $page;                
        }

    }

    /* All done we don't have more items in the list. */
    return 'content_' . $page;
}else{
    /* Page not found */
    return 'content_404';
}
```